Stuck fruit leather silicone tray
OK, I’ve read on some of the responses on different things on the sticking of fruit leather. However, you guys are giving tips and tricks and how to prevent it. I need to know how to get it off the silicone tray. I’ve already dehydrated it and it will not come off of that tray how do I get it off the tray it’s already done. I just need to know how to get it off next time, I will follow the tips and tricks but right now I have a very big problem. Cannot get it off silicone Tray.

Was it warm or cool when you tried to remove it from the tray?

It shouldn’t completely stick to silicone once fully dehydrated. You may have dried it too quickly, causing case hardening: the top is  fully dry but underneath it isn’t. Continue dehydrating it for another 12 hours or so and it should come off.
If it doesn’t, well, scrubbing and soaking should do the trick (and I wouldn't use the same silpat for it again).
